# Where can I find PokeLabs in Africa, Asia and South America?

Tags: google-maps-pokemon

While "hunting" on Google maps I visited pokelabs in Australia, US and Europe. They usually had bunch of Pokemons I didn't have before. So I was wondering did anyone visited pokelabs in Africa, Asia and South America? And if yes, could you point out their location?

Answer (score 1):

I have found only two in the regions you specified, but here are the ones I found:

- Roppongi Hills, Japan
- Trou Aux Cerfs, Mauritius